# Proper way to model a child class with properties from its relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, solid-principles

I have a `Lawsuit` class that has an `Employer` list. There's a requirement that one of the employers on the list must be set as the main employer. I thought of two ways to meet this business rule.

**Solution 1**

This is my current implementation, I have a `MainEmployer` and I store the same entity on this property and on the `Employers` list:

```
public class Lawsuit()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Employer MainEmployer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employer> Employers { get; set; }
}
```

**Solution 2**

I could also create an in-between class `EmployerLawsuit` with a *bool* property called `Main`:

```
public class LawsuitEmployer()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Main { get; set; }

    public virtual Employer Employer { get; set; }
    public virtual Lawsuit Lawsuit { get; set; }
}

public class Lawsuit()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployerLawsuit> Employers { get; set; }
}
```

Which of these two approaches is better considering the performance of the resulting database (I'm using Entity Framework) and the principles of SOLID? Or is there a better way to model these entities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd stick with **#1 approach**. It's just an one-to-many/many-to-one association between a `Lawsuit` and an `Employer`. That is, the so-called association will be retrieved as part of a *SQL join* when retrieving a `Lawsuit` persistent object, and in addition, you won't need to query all employers to check which one is the *main employer*.

In terms of object-oriented programming **#1** sounds better and the domain will perform better when mapped to either a relational or NoSQL database using an O/RM.

### About #2

Actually #2 sounds more like designing the domain the relational way. It would be a domain designed to be *queryable*, while object-oriented programming produces *hierarchical models*, and that's the main reason to express your domain with associations rather than using flags or identifiers to define the relationships of your domain entities.

You don't need a flag to mark an entity *as the main employer* and implement a hierarchy for this. Keep it simple: set the whole `MainEmployer` association and go!